# How to specify the CLI (driver properties) in a PHP PDO connection?

Tags: ssl, pdo, db2, websphere

Here is a tough one.  So I managed to connect to our IBM DB2 database using Windows ODBC DNS method and via the catalogued name.  I have the php_pdo_ibm.dll module loaded and it works when connecting doing:

```
$connection = new PDO('ibm:SomeDB2CataloguedDBName');
```

The catalogued name (ie: alias) does have the following specified:

```
db2 update dbm cfg using SSL_CLNT_STASH "C:\somefile.kdb"

db2 update dbm cfg using SSL_CLNT_KEYDB "C:\somefile.kdb"
```

In the ODBC screen, those parameters are also specified in the Advanced Settings screen:

[image]

I know that I can connect using the ODBC connection even if the DB2 DB alias has not been set up as the 3 required SSL parameters are specified there in the db2cli.ini file.

My question is, how can I use the new PDO(.....) in PHP without referencing the DB2 alias nor the ODBC DNS?  I expect I would need some sort of special connection string?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-ibm.connection.php#example-1139), which shows an example of connecting via either a DSN alias , or via a connection string with explicit properties.

Both methods should let you make the connection with SSL successfully, assuming your environment is correctly configured.

For connecting with explicitly URL connection string, You need to know the correct Db2 driver name (which may differ from the one shown in the documentation) - your question does not mention which Db2 driver type you are using.

From that documentation page here is a connection URL example:

`$db = new PDO(
"ibm:DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=testdb;" .
"HOSTNAME=11.22.33.444;PORT=56789;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=testuser;PWD=testpass",
"",
"");`

Depending on the Db2 driver name and version, you can add connection properties in the `db2dsdriver.cfg` XML file (for use with the DSN connection method), or you can place these properties in the connection URL along with any other required properties to make the connection work.

If you are using a Db2 driver that is recent (newer than year 2016) then you can get an SSL connection from CLI applications (like PHP) without needing to use a statically created keystore and without needing to separately deploy the IBM GSK8. This is possible if you have the Db2-instance (or server) certificate in ARM file format and you supply its fully qualified name with the connection attribute `SSLServerCertificate="c:/path/to/certificate file";` along with `Security=SSL`, assuming your target Db2-server environment is already suitably configured.  For details, refer to the Db2 Knowledge center for you Db2 server version.

Comment: Very detailed and nice.  Adding Security=SSL to the connection string did the trick.  Thank you.